# 192.168.x.x with Subnet 255.255.0.0, would like to link with 192.168.2.x with subnet 255.255.255.0

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

Is it possible to connect these two networks together, without changing the subnet? For example by putting a router in between.

Network A
IP  :192.168.x.X
Sub :255.255.0.0

Network B
IP  : 192.168.2.X
Sub :255.255.255.0

Thank you

Comment: are you sure that your Network A Subnet Mask is correct? It doesn't fit to the Network.

Comment: Based on the CIDR size, i will have 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255. I do understand i don't follow the standard class c

Comment: @MarinAlthuis It is perfectly valid. [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) has been used since the mid-1990s. Classful network allocations have been deprecated for the last two decades. All of 192.168/16 is allocated for private use by RFC 1918.

Comment: Since you specify 192.168.1.0/16, what is the reason you don't want to change the subnet mask length? Going 192.168.1.0/24 would make this trivial, as the smaller subnet would no longer fall inside (and as a special case in) the larger subnet.

Comment: Network A have link with alot of device, therefore i am thinking whether there is a way to solve it, instead of reconfigure all the existing IP in the network, or just simply add a router which already have

Comment: Are we to infer that neither subnet uses DHCP?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I was suspecting a typo, because he wrote 192.168.1.X with 255.255.0.0. With that subnet mask, it would be 192.168.X.X. Of course you don't have to follow network classes anymore.

Comment: Yes. It's 192.168.X.X in network A. my mistake...

Comment: This question seems to be in need of some clarification. I have voted to put it on hold until the details can be ironed out, such that we will be able to answer it properly. Ice, please take a few moments to [edit] your question and incorporate the information that has been requested so far in comments into the question itself. (Comments are meant to be ephemeral.) Also, if you can include a diagram showing the physical network layout, that might help us give you a good answer that addresses your situation as well as that it's useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you shouldn't: Because of network A's subnet mask, network A can have valid addresses starting with `192.168.2.x`. If network B happens to not have these addresses, you can link them together with a router, but it is likely that said router will struggle as any addresses beginning with `192.168.2.x` could possibly exist on both networks and thus having multiple routes to the same address, where just one would work. I strongly recommend against it.

Your best approach is to alter the network setup so that network A has a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`. Alternatively, you can change network B to `255.255.0.0` which would make them one network, eliminating the need for a router. Without looking too much into it, I'm sure you can find a CIDR mask that you can use, but either way, changing the subnet mask is the way forward.